# how to dynamically draw markers on google map

Tags: ajax, google-maps

Since the markers are too many and data is very large. I want to only draw the screen bounded region of markers. while I pan to other region, I can dynamically issue new request only for those not-shown markers. In case of overlapping region, the original-shown markers should not be re-drawn. For some reason,I need to use python as the back-end server script.A typical ajax approach should be used I think.

One problem is A new request may cover the original region of markers. A small move may cause the whole region to be re-drawn. Is there any cache-like thing to remember the previous region data so that the same portion of data won't be sent.
Is there any way to do this? Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take a look at the different approaches described here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markermanager

The Markermanager might be what you're looking for:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm You sure have a database with the markers, you can make a web service from server side expose a json response, then you can consume that web service from a ajax call.

The web service have doing a query in database with the current position of users  (Using geolocation html5 or current mid point in google maps). The answer must be a array of the markers in the zone.

Comment: Thanks, A new request may cover the original region of markers. A small move may cause the whole region to be re-drawn. Is there any cache-like thing to remember the previous region data so that the same portion of data won't be sent.

Answer (score 0):

the google map api [example][1]

[1]: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-arguments  should resolve your problem